# Python - Error in recursion doesn't return string variable

Tags: python, string, recursion, path

I am building a Python Application that searches files with a given path and returns them.

This is the code:

```
def search(path):
    name = 'filename'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for filename in files:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if name in fullname and 'rat' not in fullname:
            print(colored('[*] Found: '+fullname+' [*]','blue'))
            return ''+fullname
        elif os.path.isdir(fullname):
            return search(fullname)
```

When i run this piece of code:

```
path = search('output/host/smali/')
code = 'invoke-super {p0, p1}, Lcom/example/rat/activity/MainActivity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V'
into = 'invoke-static,onCreate'
print(path+' '+code+' '+into)
```

The Application launches this Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bane.py", line 48, in <module>
    login(creds[0],creds[1])
  File "./bane.py", line 16, in login
    bane = baneshell(username)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/baneshell.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.start()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/baneshell.py", line 36, in start
    self.execute(command)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/baneshell.py", line 26, in execute
    rat.rat(self.username)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/modules/rat/rat.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.start()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/modules/rat/rat.py", line 18, in start
    self.execute(command)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/modules/rat/rat.py", line 42, in execute
    inject.inject(command.replace('inject',''),self.address,self.port)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/modules/rat/rat_modules/injector.py", line 101, in inject
    injectcode(address,port)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/stecco/Desktop/bane/modules/rat/rat_modules/injector.py", line 75, in injectcode
    print(path+' '+code+' '+into)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

**Update: the code is printing nothing in method search before returning the fullname variable**

Comment: What is the line number for this error? Share complete trace please!

Comment: Ok, i update the error if it is needed i show the entire code.

Comment: As printed in exception message this error comes when you try to concatenate None and some string variable. In your case either "path", "code" or "into" can be None. Can you please print all these variable differently eg. print path, print code, print into. And also print full stack trace as pointed by Hamza Khurshid

Comment: If `os.listdir(path)` finds no files, `search()` will return `None`.

Comment: code and into are string previously decleared, i update the code and show the 3 variables.

Comment: Your search method is returning nothing. As your method doesn't return when your conditions doesn't satisfy. Print in loop of your method immediately before return to check if it even returns anything.

Comment: print files variable to see is there any files in given path.

Comment: is there anyway to do this without using recursion?

Comment: Your recursion searches only the first sub(sub)directory it finds.  Fixing that will make it obvious what is happening here.

Comment: I don't understand, can someone please provide some code example or give me the solution?